# Should I use anything other than xs for bootstrap when columns are same across viewports?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

If an element is to be displayed at 4 columns wide regardless of viewport size, is there any reason to not use just the xs class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer. No. the `*-xs-*` classes are not wrapped in any media queries so by design they are kind of the default, and unless you specify something else, such as a `col-sm-*` class, then the `*-xs-*` class will be applied throughout all screen sizes. So in your specific case, if you always wanted something 4 columns wide the `col-xs-4` class would be the right way to go.

Just remember that 4 columns on a very small screen (i.e. a phone) is a very small area, so don't try and stick anything important or potentially long in there!